# How to put Text in two lines inside a box

Tags: math-mode, boxes

```
\rightline{\fbox{LEMA 2: $(a^m-1,a^n-1)=a^d-1$\newline onde, $d=(m,n)$}}
```

This command generates this

[image]

I wanted to pass this `onde d = (m, n)` to the line below, but keeping within the box ... How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried \\ instead of `\newline`?  Also, have you thought about using `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` to box your equation?

Comment: @dustin Yes I've tried using the "\\" and also not given.

Comment: I posted a `tcolorbox` option you may want to consider.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion with `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
%  adding examples to cleverref                                                     
\crefname{exa}{lemma}{lemma}%                                                  
\Crefname{exa}{Lemma}{Lemma}%   
\tcbset{
  theorem/.style args = {#1#2#3#4}{%                                                
    step and label = {#2}{#4},%                                                     
    title = {\mbox{#1~\csname the#2\endcsname\ }#3:}}
}
\newcounter{exa}
\tcbmaketheorem{lemma}{Lemma}{
  breakable,
  colback = blue!10,
  fonttitle = \bfseries,
}{exa}{ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}{To index the counter}{uniquename}
  This is so your lemma will have the same counter 2.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}{description or blank}{uniquename2}
  \((a^m-1,a^n-1) = a^d-1\)\\
  onde, \(d =(m,n)\)
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> `\begin{lemma}{}{name}`
>
> The first `{}` is for a description if you would like. It can be left blank.
>
> The second `{name}` will allow you to reference the the Lemma.
>
> Additionally, the lemmas will index themselves for you starting with 1, 2, 3, ..

Answer (score 1):

got it

```
\rightline{\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
LEMA 2: $(a^m-1,a^n-1)=a^d-1$\\
onde, $d=(m,n)$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
```

Comment: I like this one better.